# Get only 1 result from SQL table (null or with date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name `ItemMedia` with 2 rows

```
ID   Source    FromDate     ToDate
----------------------------------
122  122A.jpg  NULL         NULL
122  122B.jpg  1/1/14       1/2/14
```

I want to return only one row if today is not between the `FromDate` to the `ToDate` return the row with NULL values in 'FromDate' and 'ToDate'

I've tried this SQL statement

```
IF (SELECT ItemID FROM ItemsMedia 
WHERE (FromDate<=GETDATE() AND ToDate>=GETDATE())) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT Source FROM ItemsMedia 
WHERE (FromDate<=GETDATE() AND ToDate>=GETDATE())
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT Source FROM ItemsMedia 
    WHERE (FromDate IS NULL AND ToDate IS NULL)
END
```

Which is working but the the source is part of other related tables (ItemText, ItemDetails and more) and i need to return all of them as one result. So the `Source` i get from the statement is part of a larger SQL statement so i can get this sample end result

```
ID    Source    Text        Details
----------------------------------
122   122B.jpg  Some Text   Some Details
```

Comment: ms-sql? my-sql? also question is not very clear, what is the definition of related tables?

Comment: I tagged it as SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to return one row with some precedence rules. You can do that with `top` and `order by`:

```
SELECT top 1 im.*
FROM ItemsMedia im
ORDER BY (case when FromDate <= GETDATE() AND ToDate >= GETDATE()
               then 1
               when FromDate IS NULL AND ToDate IS NULL
               then 2
               else 3
          end);
```